# saving url parameters on page load/click

Tags: php, file, url, parameters

```
<a href="http://www.example.co.uk?id=<?=rand(1, 1000000); ?>"> ....
```

I have this link, I need to save the random id into a text file every time the page is refreshed, or every time the link is actually clicked (whichever is easiest).

Answer (score 1):

see [fopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) for handling files. And please research a bit on google or something, or on [php.net](http://www.php.net) before asking :D